# update params hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I need a way to modify the params hash. I tried a couple of things but none of it actually worked.

```
Unpermitted parameters: :players, :leaders
```

**Params**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"asa", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"anikeeet", "last_name"=>"tiwariii", "friend_attributes"=>{"players"=>"50589,50590", "leaders"=>"16,6,18", "phone_number"=>"", "title"=>"aasdassd", "role"=>"abcdef"}}}
```

I tried this way

```
(friend_params.dig(:friend_attributes) || []).each do |_, attributes|
      attributes['players'] = attributes['players'].split(',').map(&:to_i)
      attributes['leaders'] = attributes['leaders'].split(',').map(&:to_i)
    end
```

this way

```
(friend_params.dig(:friend_attributes) || []).each do |key, val|
  friend_params["friend_attributes"]["#{key}"] = val.split(',').map(&:to_i) if key == 'players' || key == 'leaders'
end
```

this way

```
(params.dig(:user, :friend_attributes) || []).each do |key, val|
  params["user"]["friend_attributes"]["#{key}"] = val.split(',').map(&:to_i) if key == 'players' || key == 'leaders'
end
```

and this way

```
 if (attributes = params.dig(:user, :friend_attributes))
      %i[players leaders].each do |key|
        next unless attributes.has_key?(key)
        attributes[key] = attributes[key].split(',').map(&:to_i)
      end
    end
```

But none of the ways worked for me. I am sharing my full controller code

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    # (friend_params.dig(:friend_attributes) || []).each do |_, attributes|
    #   attributes['players'] = attributes['players'].split(',').map(&:to_i)
    #   attributes['leaders'] = attributes['leaders'].split(',').map(&:to_i)
    # end

    # (friend_params.dig(:friend_attributes) || []).each do |key, val|
    #   friend_params["friend_attributes"]["#{key}"] = val.split(',').map(&:to_i) if key == 'players' || key == 'leaders'
    # end

    # (params.dig(:user, :friend_attributes) || []).each do |key, val|
    #   params["user"]["friend_attributes"]["#{key}"] = val.split(',').map(&:to_i) if key == 'players' || key == 'leaders'
    # end

     if (attributes = params.dig(:user, :friend_attributes))
       %i[players leaders].each do |key|
         next unless attributes.has_key?(key)
         attributes[key] = attributes[key].split(',').map(&:to_i)
       end
     end


    if current_user.update(friend_params)
      render json: { success: true }
    else
      render json: {error: "something went wrong"}
    end
  end

  private
  def friend_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, friend_attributes: [:phone_number, :title, :role, :players, :leaders])
  end
end
```

Association

```
Class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_one :friend, foreign_key: :user_id, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :friend
end

class Friend < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'schema.friends'
  belongs_to :user
end
```

players and leaders are the array field stored in friends table
Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are `Players` and `Leaders` their own Model or is this data stored on the Friend?

Comment: Is there some reason that the value of `"authenticity_token"` in your example needs to be 90 characters in length? Examples should be as small as possible while still conveying the essence of the problem.  Also, if you write `params = {"utf8"=>"✓", ....}`, readers can simply cut-and-paste.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Nice suggestion I will keep that in mind

Comment: @whodini9 players and leaders are the array field stored in friends model. My association is user has one friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do the job:

```
if (attributes = params.dig(:user, :friend_attributes))
  %i[players leaders].each do |key|
    next unless attributes.has_key?(key)
    attributes[key] = attributes[key].split(',').map(&:to_i)
  end
end
```

The problem currently lies in `(friend_params.dig(:friend_attributes) || []).each` which loops though the key-value pairs, or if not present through an empty array. You then call the `#[]` method on the value (which is a string). eg. `"50589,50590"['players']` tries the find the substring `'players'` inside `"50589,50590"` the result of this should be `nil`. Followed by an "NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass" exception.

You should simply use the returned collection, rather than looping through the key-value pairs.

---

The better question is, why do you need to transform your parameters at all?

Can't the view be arranged in such a way to provide the parameters in array format?

```html
<input name="user[friend_attributes][players][]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="user[friend_attributes][players][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input name="user[friend_attributes][players][]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
```

Would send an array of numbers to the controller to start with, eliminating the need to convert parameters into the correct format.

**Note:** If you supply the parameters in the above format you should update your permited params to:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, friend_attributes: [:phone_number, :title, :role, players: [], leaders: []])
# players and leaders are now expecting an array instead of a scalar value
```

Comment: If you've never seen the `%i[...]` notation, you can find the documentation [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings).

Comment: From the view, it is not possible because I am sending this data from javascript. Also, the above solution you gave didn't work for me. Let me update your solution in my question

Comment: From the view, it is not possible because I am sending this data from javascript. Also, the above solution you gave didn't work for me. Let me update your solution in my question

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Supplying the parameters through JavaScript only makes the request more customizable. Could you add the way you compose the request parameters and make the request?

Comment: @3limi4t0r Thanks It worked now. I was making a silly mistake. Instead of permitting leaders and players as an array. I was giving it as a string

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari I've updated the answer to better clarify that you should update the permitted params, since that wasn't clear enough apparently.

Comment: @3limi4t0r Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your params are hash, require and permit method are instance method of ActionController::Parameters. Also you try dig by symbol instead string.

```
params.dig('user', 'friend_attributes')
```

Or if you want to continue using the symbol you can write it like this

```
params.with_indifferent_access.dig(:user, :friend_attributes)
```

Please, read more about with_indifferent_access method.

:)

Comment: *"You can fetch values of `ActionController::Parameters` using either `:key` or `"key"`."* - [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) There is no need to use `with_indifferent_access`.

Comment: Maybe include a link to where you can read about that method?